# Convert address into a number that PyKD can work with / equivalent of the WinDbg ? command

Tags: python, windbg, pykd

In WinDbg, I have several options to define a number

```
0:006> ? 17
Evaluate expression: 23 = 00000017
0:006> ? 0x17
Evaluate expression: 23 = 00000017
0:006> ? 0n23
Evaluate expression: 23 = 00000017
0:006> ? ntdll
Evaluate expression: 2004549632 = 777b0000
0:006> ? ntdll+100
Evaluate expression: 2004549888 = 777b0100
0:006> ? ntdll!NtCreateThreadEx
Evaluate expression: 2005018944 = 77822940
0:006> ? 0t755
Evaluate expression: 493 = 000001ed
0:006> ? 0y1111
Evaluate expression: 15 = 0000000f
```

I am looking for the PyKD equivalent to use all these possibilities as an input for my script.

That is: I get a string in `sys.argv[1]` which could be in any of the above mentioned formats and I need to convert it into an address that PyKD can understand.

I have tried:

```
from pykd import *
address = addr64(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PyKd command is [`expr()`](https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykd/-/wikis/API%20Reference#expr).

> expr( (str)expression [, (bool)cplusplus]) -> object :
>
> Evaluate windbg expression

The command will even consider the number base that has been set in WinDbg using the `n` command.

To simulate WinDbg's `?` behavior, you can use

```
print("Evaluate expression:", expr(sys.argv[1]), "=", hex(expr(sys.argv[1])), sep=" ")
```